# jQuery how to select th inside a table id

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I select only the `<th>`s from the following code using jQuery selector? Thanks!

```
<table id='tab1'>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>col1</th>
      <th>col2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      ...
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Have you read a basic jQuery tutorial, because this is about as basic as you can get.

Answer (score 3):

Use the following:

```
$("#tab1 th")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var th = $( '#tab1 th' );
```

or

```
var th = $( 'th', '#tab1' );
```